# Proving that a language cannot be generated by linear grammar

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

We were said at school that the language $L$ over an alphabet $\sum = \{a,b\}$ where the number of $a$'s is twice the number of $b$'s, formally $L = \{ w \in \{a,b\}^* \mid |w|_a = 2|w|_b  \}$ cannot be generated by linear grammar. 
I was wondering, is there a way to prove it, to make it clear why is that so?
I was thinking about applying the pumping lemma might work, but I wasn't succesful proving it.

Comment: Of course you can not use the Pumping lemma; not the context-free one, at least. The language *is* context-free, after all!

Comment: Hint: proof by contradiction. Assume it was linear, so you'd have a linear grammar. Now build a derivation for a word not in the language.

Comment: Well, recently we saw a [pumping lemma for linear languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/73791/4287).