# Prove $\{xy \mid |x|=|y|, x \neq y\}$ is not a linear language

Tags: pumping-lemma, linear-languages

> Show the language
>
> $$L = \{xy \mid |x| = |y|, x\neq y\}$$
>
> is not linear.

I've seen and proved a pumping lemma for linear languages, mentioned [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/73791/pumping-lemma-for-linear-languages):

> If $L$ is linear then there exists a constant $p$ such that for all $w \in L$ with $|w| \ge p$ there is a decomposition $w = uvxyz$ such that:
>
> 1. $|uvyz| \leq p$.
> 2. $|vy| > 0$.
> 3. $uv^ix^iz \in L$ for all $i \geq 0$.

I'm trying to find a counterexample string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this string: $w=a^kb^ka^{2k+2k!}b^ka^k$. We will show that we can't write this string in form of $uvxyz$ in a way that the conditions of pumping lemma for linear languages statisfy.

Because $|uvyz|\leq k$ we have :  $|uv|\leq k$ and $|yz|\leq k$

So we can write: $uv=a^{f_1}$ ,  $yz=a^{f_2}$ ,   $y=a^{g_1}$ , $v=a^{g_2}$ where $g_1+g_2>0$ (because  $yv$  is cannot be empty string) and $g_1+g_2\leq k$.

Now we pump $v$ and $y$  $n$-times and we have: $w'=a^{k+ng_1}b^ka^{2k+2k!}b^ka^{k+ng_2}$

We want to conclude this string is not in language for some $n$. So if we rewrite $w'$ as $w'=a^{k+ng_1}b^ka^xa^{2k+2k!-x}b^ka^{k+ng_2}$,

we should have:
$k+ng_1=2k+2k!-x$  and  $x=k+ng_2$

so $k+ng_1=2k+2k!-k-ng_2 \to n(g_1+g_2)=2k! \to n=\frac{2k!}{g_1+g_2}$.

Notice that $g_1\leq k , g_2 \leq k \to g_1+g_2 \leq 2k$  $\to$  $g_1+g_2| 2k!$

So we only need to set $n=\frac{2k!}{g_1+g_2}$ to have $w'=w''w''$ and this is a contradiction. So $L$ is not linear.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be the constant promised by the pumping lemma. Without loss of generality, $p \geq 2$.

Let $w = 0^p 1 0^{2p+p!} 1 0^p$. Since the left half of $w$ is $0^p10^{p+p!/2}$ and the right half of $w$ is $0^{p+p!/2}10^p$, we see that $w \in L$.

Let $w = uvxyz$ be the decomposition promised by the pumping lemma. Since $|uvyz| \leq p$, necessarily $v = 0^j$ and $y = 0^k$ belong to the first and last zero runs, respectively, and $j+k \leq p$. Since $|vy| > 0$, we have $j+k > 0$.

Let $i = 1 + p!/(j+k)$. According to the pumping lemma, $uv^ixy^iz \in L$. But
$$
 uv^ixy^iz = 0^{p + jp!/(j+k)} 1 0^{2p+p!} 1 0^{p + kp!/(j+k)}.
$$
The total length of this word is $2(2p+p!+1)$. Therefore its left half and its right half are both equal to
$$
0^{p + jp!/(j+k)} 1 0^{p + kp!/(j+k)},
$$
showing that $uv^ixy^iz \notin L$, in contradiction to the pumping lemma.